# Angular2 - The requested url was not found on this server

Tags: angular, api, http, localhost, port

I have an angular2 app, and its hitting an `api` which is placed in my `wamp/www` . When i try to hit the api i get this error.

> 404 Not Found
>
> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /usmanproject/api/web/v1/users was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

My angular app is running on `localhost:4200`and the angular project folder is also placed in `wamp/www` but it is not working.

This is my angular code

```
 private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost/usmanproject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0';  // URL to web api

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });


    create(): Promise<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.heroesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

The backend is made in `yii2`. I have tested the `api` `http://localhost/usmanproject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0` in postman, its working perfectly fine over there.

[image]

Its working fine in google chrome but not on firefox.

Comment: is your api running on port 80?

Comment: no its not. its just simple running like this localhost/usmanproject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0

Comment: You told us nothing about your backend, so one can only guess and ask additional questions. You should include at least some info about you verifying the backend really runs at the URL you wrote.

Comment: let me write it

Comment: Do you have enabled the 'cors' in web Api

Comment: Yea cors error was coming i used cors extension and the error is solved. Now the api is not working :(

Comment: Can you post the error what you are getting?

Comment: In configurationservices  and configure method you need to use cores  like:  services.AddCors();    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

Comment: i am getting this error sir, not cors,  404 Not Found
Not Found

The requested URL /usmanproject/api/web/v1/users was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154409/discussion-between-vignesh-and-usman-iqbal).

Comment: why do you set headers like xxx-form.url-encoded ? ..are you sure it is not a json ?

Comment: yes bro, let me attach a screen shot too.

Comment: see the image @ffederico

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your virtual hosts where it redirect the project.
on Angular it will redirect on **dist/projectName/** and there you should add an .htaccess that should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```